# Change header of fasta file with sequential numbers

Tags: bash, awk, sed, gsub, fasta

How to change with awk/sed/grep the header of more fasta sequences in a file like:

```
>chromosome1|2199-2200
----------------------

>chromosome1|3546-3548
----------------------

>chromosome1|6489-6548
----------------------
```

to this:

```
>chromosome1-1|2199-2200
------------------------

>chromosome1-2|3546-3548
------------------------

>chromosome1-3|6489-6548
------------------------
```

At the moment I just can add a sequential number at the beginning or end of the name like:

`awk '/^>/{gsub(/^>/,">Seq"i++" ");}1'`

```
>Seq1chromosome1|2199-2200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '/>/{sub(/\|/,"-"++i"|")}1' file
>chromosome1-1|2199-2200
----------------------

>chromosome1-2|3546-3548
----------------------

>chromosome1-3|6489-6548
----------------------
```